# Initiate paypal refund online in magento

Tags: paypal, magento-community, refund

is it possible to initiate paypal refund online in magento community? if yes, please let me know how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you use PayPal Express checkout method.
The downside of this is that by using this method you add and extra step to the checkout process. Hope it help or point you in the right direction.